# Installing pip on OS X 10.6

Tags: python, pip

I've spent hours trying to figure out how to install pip. I tried following the steps in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBdZZGPpYxg but then every time I enter `sudo python get-pip.py`, it gives me this error: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pip`

So then I tried entering `sudo easy_install pip` and it gave me back: `sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory`

Anybody know how to solve this issue and get pip installed? Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get `get-pip.py`? Also, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.9+ comes with pip already installed, so just upgrade Python if you haven't already

Comment: and well, it's time to upgrade your osx.

Answer (score -1):

On MacOS you can try using homebrew, that will help you to get latest python and pip along with it.

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then doing

```
brew install python
```

without sudo will get you the latest python and pip.

Comment: None of that worked. I think my problem is that I upgraded Python from 2.6 to 2.7 using Homebrew, and now when I type in the command `which python`, I receive the following path: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`. I need to manually reset the path to `/usr/local/bin/python` and I'm not sure how to do it. Do you know how?